# What layout will be the best way to design this android screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Want to design an android screen where profiles of other users will be shown on the screen along with there profile photos ?

Should I go for having fragments for each of the player profile and list them in rectangular fragment ?

Any other best way to do this in android ?

Comment: could you make an image by paint and post it here ?

Comment: May be better suited for the [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using the relatively new RecyclerView. You can then choose among different layout managers, such as GridLayoutManager or LinearLayoutManager. Some libraries out there make it easier to implement all this, plus provide additional functionalities, like [SuperRecyclerView](https://github.com/Malinskiy/SuperRecyclerView).

Comment: Thanks @ticofab...I am a new bie to andriod...but this was actually I was looking for....I think RecyclerView will be the best fit...

Comment: Cool @rahulfhp_opensource_geek :) if that is what you were looking for, could you please accept my answer?